# Function selfiexecuting in var

Tags: javascript

Can somebody tell me, can I in javascript declare a function into var and execute it in the same experession(program-line)?

```
var tmp = 0,
a = function() {
    ++tmp; /*rest of code*/
};
a();
console.log(tmp);
```

Comment: What happens if you stick that into the console? Does it work?

Comment: Have you tried _doing it_?

Comment: I got 1, i want to get 2: once incrementation in function initialization and next one in function  execute

Comment: @Kamczatka Why not just call it immediately after the declaration?

Answer (score 1):

if you surround a function declaration with parentesis you get an expression.
an assigment is also an expression (is evaluated as the value assigned) and you can leverage this fact to obtains your result.

```js
var tmp = 0, a;
(a = function() { ++tmp;})();
a();
console.log(tmp);
```

Said that, to me, I wouldn't like to have to read code like this. It is prone to errors and misinterpretation.